# how to get the list of applications opened in system tray using java

Tags: java, swing

I found this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661198/how-to-find-the-names-of-currently-opened-applications-on-taskbar-in-windows) to get the currently opened applications in task bar.

1. In addition I need to get the applications running in system tray using Java.
2. Also suggest me if there is some other good ways to find the opened apps in task bar.
3. How to find in which application the mouse click and key stroke has been ocuured?
4. I also want to track the mouse click by viewing which application is opened by the particular mouse click.

I want this application to run both in Linux and windows environment. I need to do all the above in one of my application using Java.

Comment: *"I need to get the applications running in system tray using JAVA."* a) Why? b) It is spelled Java, not JAVA or java.

Comment: please for why reason you need to know about that,

Comment: That is really two different questions you have there. (list of apps in system tray and currently opened application). You should break them apart. Maybe add some code to question to show what you tried.

Comment: @jschoen Thanks for your response. I have updated my post. for now I tried with tasklist.exe.

Comment: @mKorbel I need to implement in one of my application. Also updated my question.

Comment: one SystemTray have got a few windows, or you can to generated a few SystemTrays for a few windows

Comment: *"I need to implement in one of my application."*  That does not answer my question as to 'why?'.  Let's try this a different way.  What application feature are you hoping to offer to the end user?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I want to know how many applications I am opening in a day and to know my system performance.

Comment: All this 'my/I' suggestes you are the only user.  In that case, there are likely existing software to do that.  Why bother write it in Java?